# How can I create a table widget using Qt

Tags: qt

I know how to use QTableview or QTablewidget
but if I have to create a table with 30 thousands rows
It seems that QTableview or QTablewidget is not useful;
So how can I create a table widget by using Qt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How is QTableView or QTableWidget not useful ?

I used QTableWidget. This code shows 30000 rows;

EDIT: i inserted some data into each cell

table.h

```
#ifndef TABLE_H
#define TABLE_H

#include <QDialog>

#include <QTableWidgetItem>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

class Table : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Table(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Table();

private:
    QTableWidget *table;

};

#endif // TABLE_H
```

table.cpp

```
#include "table.h"
#include "ui_table.h"

Table::Table(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent) {

    //doing this creates the table, then you set the row count
    table = new QTableWidget;
    table->setRowCount(30000);
    table->setColumnCount(1);

    //QTableWidgetItem puts data into each cell. Just an example
    for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
            QTableWidgetItem *item = new     
            QTableWidgetItem(tr("%1").arg(pow(i, j+1)));
            table->setItem(i, j, item);
        }
    }

    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(table);

    setLayout(layout);
}

Table::~Table() {
    delete table;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "table.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Table *window = new Table;
    window->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: It will fail when I want to put data in each cells

Comment: @dantegg i have updated my answer. You should have added to your question that it fails when you put data in each cell though.

Comment: I have found another way to solve this problem,anyway, thank u for ur answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can take QTableView, create your own model for it. It's no need to show all 30000 rows for user in any moment.

Comment: I want to show the data of one table in Oracle, so there is a need if users want to see all rows;

Comment: @dantegg ...actually, you should be using a model to load only those rows that are visible at any given time. You *don't* need to show all 30000 rows at once (it isn't even possible).

Comment: @trooper,that's true! I have already solved this problem like u said , ty 4 ur suggestion